# Phantom boxes in an Access 2007 form when viewed in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have an Access db (developed in Access 2007) set to display windows in tabbed view. It opens with a simple form to show the user various options. Since I made it, we upgraded to Access 2010.

Since this form was made for navigation to other forms (there is no underlying data set), it just has buttons in the Form Header that open other forms.  Here's sample code from one of those buttons:

```
Private Sub Cmd_Lookup_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Frm7a_Lookup"
End Sub
```

However, when these buttons are clicked, a dotted rectangle (about 1-2 inches in length and width) appears in the upper left of the form while the new form is loading.  I have no idea where this 'phantom box' is coming from.  There's no object in that area of the form and all the other objects in the form are visible and accounted for. So, there's nothing for me to delete.

It's visually unappealing and shouldn't exist.  How do I make this phantom box go away? Do I have to rebuild the form from scratch?

Comment: got a screen shot? (oh I just saw this is a year old...maybe it'd been solved :)

Comment: The boxes were only there while the form was loading, so I'd have had to be quick to screen shot them.  A little difficult but not impossible. In any case, now that I've upgraded my 'development environment' to 2010, the phantom boxes stopped appearing.  Looking back, my best guess is that it was caused by the difference in versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phantom boxes seem to appear when buttons (perhaps with pictures) from previous versions are on the form.

Try removing the buttons and re-adding them.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. The issue is long since moot but I kept a version of the old db lying around. Yes, there are buttons with pictures.  The pictures are the stock arrow images in Access (not custom images) and are embedded in the button. When I removed the pictures, the phantom boxes went away.  Problem solved!